# QGIS freezes when trying to view layer properties

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, windows-10

As of recently whenever I try to edit the properties of a vector layer the entire program just freezes and I'm forced to end the process using task manager. I use Windows 10. Any reasons as to why this might be happening?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Try reinstalling QGIS. Does it happen with all vector layers? Where are the layers stored? Are they really large? What happens if you just wait, give it 10 minutes or so?

Comment: Try to think what else might have happened "recently" at the same time as this issue started. Did you update QGIS? Did you change any settings in QGIS or on your computer? Did you install any new QGIS plugins? Have you noticed any changes in the performance of other programs, or just this one? Are there other programs/processes running in the background?

Comment: To answer the above, I use QGIS 3.8.1. My shapefiles are stored in a PostgreSQL database on localhost. I haven't done any major changes since this started happening. As far as plugins go I did install the qgis2web plugin. I am now trying to reinstall QGIS and will see what happens.

Comment: I have the same problem. QGIS 3.12 was working fine with Windows 10 for the last one year. I could filter an attribute table of 50k rows in a few seconds. Now it takes 2-3 minutes or more! The only things that may have changed: Windows10 update, and QGIS version 3.12.3 (and some plugins). I uninstalled 3.12.3, went back to the LTR 3.10.6, removed all the latest plugins, and the problem persists. If it is to do with some WIndows update, I have no way to figure this out. HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I, too, encountered this problem starting about a week ago. Thinking it might be a problem between QGIS and Windows 10, I started Windows in safe mode and ran QGIS 3.8.3. In safe mode, I was able to view layer properties dialogues without the program freezing.

I can't explain it, but when I then restarted Windows 10 in normal mode, I can now view layer properties without QGIS freezing, although the dialogue is a little slow to open, measured in seconds, not minutes. I don't know why this worked, but you might give it a try.

I find Windows 10 buggy, and Microsoft has a history of releasing buggy updates to Windows. Since the problem with QGIS began very recently, if running QGIS in safe mode then going back to normal mode doesn't fix the problem, or it does then the problem comes back, I'd try rolling back the latest Windows update to see whether that fixes the problem.

If you want to pinpoint what program or service might be causing a problem, try running msconfig.exe and experiment with disabling particular services. I'm not going to go there unless the problem with QGIS returns.